# How to enable CUDA Aware OpenMPI?

Tags: openmpi, openacc, ucx

I'm using OpenMPI and I need to enable CUDA aware MPI. Together with MPI I'm using OpenACC with the hpc_sdk software.

Following https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=buildcuda I downloaded and installed UCX (not gdrcopy, I haven't managed to install it) with

**./contrib/configure-release --with-cuda=/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/20.7/cuda/11.0 CC=pgcc CXX=pgc++ --disable-fortran**

and it prints:

```
checking cuda.h usability... yes
checking cuda.h presence... yes
checking for cuda.h... yes
checking cuda_runtime.h usability... yes
checking cuda_runtime.h presence... yes
checking for cuda_runtime.h... yes
```

So UCX seems to be ok.
After this I re-configured OpenMPI with:

**./configure --with-ucx=/home/marco/Downloads/ucx-1.9.0/install --with-cuda=/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/20.7/cuda/11.0 CC=pgcc CXX=pgc++ --disable-mpi-fortran**

and it prints:

```
CUDA support: yes
Open UCX: yes
```

If I try to run the application with: **mpirun -np 2 -mca pml ucx -x ./a.out** (as suggested on openucx.org) I get the errors:

```
match_arg (utils/args/args.c:163): unrecognized argument mca
HYDU_parse_array (utils/args/args.c:178): argument matching returned error
parse_args (ui/mpich/utils.c:1642): error parsing input array
HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (ui/mpich/utils.c:1694): unable to parse user arguments
main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:148): error parsing parameters
```

I see that the directories the compilers is looking for are not the OpenMPI ones but the ones of MPICH, I don't know why. If i type `which mpicc` ,`which mpiexec` and `which mpirun` I get the ones of OpenMPI.

If i run with: **mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out** I get:

```
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

EDITED:

Doing the same but using the OpenMPI-4.0.5 that comes with NVIDIA HPC SDK it compiles and runs fine.

I get:

```
[marco-Inspiron-7501:1356251:0:1356251] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: invalid permissions for mapped object at address 0x7f05cfafa000)
==== backtrace (tid:1356251) ====
 0  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucs.so.0(ucs_handle_error+0x67) [0x7f060ae06dc7]
 1  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucs.so.0(+0x2ab87) [0x7f060ae06b87]
 2  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucs.so.0(+0x2ace4) [0x7f060ae06ce4]
 3  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7f060c7433c0]
 4  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x18e885) [0x7f060befb885]
 5  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x379e6) [0x7f060b2bd9e6]
 6  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(ucp_dt_pack+0xa5) [0x7f060b2bd775]
 7  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4d5b5) [0x7f060b2d35b5]
 8  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4b11d) [0x7f060b2d111d]
 9  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libuct.so.0(+0x1b577) [0x7f060b055577]
10  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libuct.so.0(uct_mm_ep_am_bcopy+0x75) [0x7f060b054725]
11  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4d614) [0x7f060b2d3614]
12  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4c2c7) [0x7f060b2d22c7]
13  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4b5b1) [0x7f060b2d15b1]
14  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x625bd) [0x7f060b2e85bd]
15  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x61d15) [0x7f060b2e7d15]
16  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x6121a) [0x7f060b2e721a]
17  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(ucp_tag_send_nbx+0x5ec) [0x7f060b2e65ac]
18  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libmpi.so.40(mca_pml_ucx_send+0x1a3) [0x7f060dfc3b33]
=================================
[marco-Inspiron-7501:1356252:0:1356252] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: invalid permissions for mapped object at address 0x7fd7f7afa000)
==== backtrace (tid:1356252) ====
 0  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucs.so.0(ucs_handle_error+0x67) [0x7fd82a711dc7]
 1  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucs.so.0(+0x2ab87) [0x7fd82a711b87]
 2  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucs.so.0(+0x2ace4) [0x7fd82a711ce4]
 3  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7fd82c04e3c0]
 4  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x18e885) [0x7fd82b806885]
 5  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x379e6) [0x7fd82abc89e6]
 6  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(ucp_dt_pack+0xa5) [0x7fd82abc8775]
 7  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4d5b5) [0x7fd82abde5b5]
 8  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4b11d) [0x7fd82abdc11d]
 9  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libuct.so.0(+0x1b577) [0x7fd82a960577]
10  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libuct.so.0(uct_mm_ep_am_bcopy+0x75) [0x7fd82a95f725]
11  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4d614) [0x7fd82abde614]
12  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4c2c7) [0x7fd82abdd2c7]
13  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x4b5b1) [0x7fd82abdc5b1]
14  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x625bd) [0x7fd82abf35bd]
15  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x61d15) [0x7fd82abf2d15]
16  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(+0x6121a) [0x7fd82abf221a]
17  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libucp.so.0(ucp_tag_send_nbx+0x5ec) [0x7fd82abf15ac]
18  /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk_209/Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/lib/libmpi.so.40(mca_pml_ucx_send+0x1a3) [0x7fd82d8ceb33]
=================================
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node marco-Inspiron-7501 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

The error it's caused by `pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)`

```
  double send_buf[NX_GLOB + 2*NGHOST];
  double recv_buf[NX_GLOB + 2*NGHOST];

  #pragma acc enter data create(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])

  // Top buffer
  j = jend;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0,
                recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in the 20.7 release when adding UCX support.  You can lower the optimization level to -O1 work around the problem, or update your NV HPC compiler version to 20.9 where we've resolved the issue.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-hpc-sdk-version-209-downloads

Comment: I tried to compile with **mpicc -O1 -acc -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel -w -lcudart app.c** but nothing change. I'm going to try with the update-

Comment: I update NV HPC and the errors are exactly the same. Why in the errors appears mpich and not mpi?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd check you PATH to make sure you're not accidently using a different MPICH build rather than OpenMPI.    Can you try using the OpenMPI 4 that ships with NV HPC 20.9?  ( Linux_x86_64/20.9/comm_libs/openmpi4/openmpi-4.0.5/bin/)?

Comment: Thank you, I did what you say and now it runs fine. I edited the question with the errors I get now because of the #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf). It's not clear to me how the device buffers have to passed to the MPI call. if you could help me also with this I'd be gratefull.

Comment: Looks like there may be something wrong with UCX, so I sent it to engineer for investigation.  I got a UCX error with one of my codes when using CUDA_AWARE_MPI, but not a segv so I can't be positive its the same issue.   One thing to try, is to fall back to the OpenMPI 3.1.5 version.  If that works, then it's an issue with UCX, if it still fails, then it's more likely a problem with your code.  Though in that case, I'd need a full reproducing example since I'm not seeing anything amiss with what you have above.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine with **mpirun -np 2 -mca pml ^ucx ./a.out**. It's weird because I thought ucx was necessary to CUDA aware MPI

Comment: No, UCX isn't needed for CUDA Aware MPI but does offer some improvements.  We're still investigating the UCX issue but haven't been able to root cause it just yet.

Comment: I've been working with the UCX folks who suggested setting the environment flags "UCX_MEMTYPE_CACHE=n" and "UCX_TLS=self,shm,cuda_copy".  The failures I was seeing with UCX go away after I set these variables.  Can you give them a try and see if they work for you as well?